# Pathfinding Algorithm Name

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, path-finding

Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding, two algorithms are described, followed by a "sample algorithm", which is not named.

My question:

What is the name of the algorithm described under the section " sample algorithm "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a [breadth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

Comment: Sure, but that's way too broad, so to speak. Surely there's something more specific?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom Looks like a vanilla BFS to me.  Not sure how that's too broad.

Answer (score -1):

Algorithm is commonly known as "Jarvis distance transform"

This particular algorithm is used both in image processing and path-finding.